# How to simulate and test multiple user login/logout in Flask with Flask-Login?

Tags: python, testing, flask, flask-login

Multiple session/client is required for testing multiple users' authentication process. I tried to test with `app.test_client(...)` as following code, it can test single user's login/logout functionality, but I can't make sure whether it still works when multiple user login/logout within their own session.

```
setUp, tearDown, and other branche tests...

def test_login(self):
    """Check if server can handle login successfully.
    """
    with self.client as c:
        login_res = c.post(API.login, data=self.valid_user)
        assert_equals(login_res.get_json(), {
            'data': {'userName': 'user'}, 'status': 200,
            'msg': 'login success.'
        })

def test_logout(self):
    """Check if server can handle user logout.
    """
    with self.client as c:
        # login user first
        c.post(API.login, data=self.valid_user)
        # then log out.
        res = c.get(API.logout)
        assert_equals(res.get_json(), {
            'data': {'userName': 'user'}, 'status': 200,
            'msg': 'logout success.'
        })
```